# Does Service Delivery Review occur twice a week or once in two weeks?

Tags: kanban, meetings

According to this source

https://aktiasolutions.com/kanban-cadences-kanban-feedback-loops/

Service Delivery review occurs biweekly.
But biweekly has an ambiguous meaning.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biweekly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the article strongly suggests it is once every two weeks. It is very unlikely you would need to hold a 1-2 hour delivery focused meeting twice per week, every week.

Having said that, the whole article seems way to precise. The frequency and duration of all these meetings are likely to vary depending on the organisation, the domain, the team size and many other factors.

I would suggest if you decide to follow this approach that it would be worth reviewing the frequency/duration of meetings every now and then to determine if they are working well for you.